# Can the contents of caches using non-volatile storage (i.e. SSDs) get used after a machine reboots?

Tags: ssd, cache

When caching with a non-volatile medium does data that was used the last time the machine was powered on get used again? For example would a SSD configured using [SRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Response_Technology) still hold the contents from the last time the computer was powered on and would it be able to use those contents for anything? Does this pose a security risk?

I was wondering since the next thing a computer does after it shuts down is boot up, would it make sense to have the bootup process put in the cache as part of the shutdown process? (<= I just invented a really good idea =D )

Comment: If you start up and reboot your computer several times in a row on a fresh SRT, you'll notice that it would cache some of the stuff before the Intel services stop.